# Test if a function is run from a static context

Tags: php, oop, static

I am writing a PHP class and have included a couple static functions for quick access as they are common for use and are simple in function. However they do use an object in them for database access. I will likely be using these static methods from both a static and non-static context throughout my code so I want to be able to test whether the function was called from a static or non-static context so that I can avoid creating a duplicate object if the function was called from a non-static context (this instance object and the one within the function to be used statically). Is there any way that I can test this in the function so that I can use the instance object if the function is called from a non-static context and create it's own object if the function is called from a static context?

Code Example:

```
class MyClass {
  private $db;

  function __constuct(){
    $this->db = new DBConnect();
  }

  public static function myFunction(){
    if(/* Is static */){
      $db = new DBConnect();
    } else {
      $db =& $this->db;
    }
    // Do processing with $db, etc.
  }
}
```

Comment: 5 answers, not one upvote for the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> When a method is declared as static,
>   not only is the magic variable $this
>   unavailable (returns NULL), but it is
>   impossible to tell if the function was
>   actually called from a static context.
>   A backtrace implies that for a static
>   method, calling $object->method() is
>   internally translated to
>   className::method() at run time.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: Thanks for this Shakti, that answers my question. I will just have to create an object for each of the static methods internally if I want to use them from a static context.

Comment: Or it seems that I could just declare the `$db` instance variable as static. Using `private static` on something just seems strange to me.

Answer (score 3):

You can check for non-static access only if you do not force the method to be static-only. Leave out the `static` keyword from the function declaration and test with:

```
public function myFunction(){
    if(!isset($this)) {
```

(It can still be called as static function, even though you did not declare it as such.)

Comment: Doesn't static access to a function without the static keyword produce an error?

Comment: It does generate an E_STRICT notice or warning (not sure of the classification). At least in the version I have. (These things tend to get occasionally deprecated and undeprecated.)

Answer (score 1):

Bottom line - don't make classes which contain only static functions. It is not OOP, it is just your old procedural code masquerading as oop

If you are executing functions statically, there is no $this, as there is no object.
You will end up making the `private $db` a static variable too , and use it as `self::$db`.

That said, i would recommend to drop this pattern and write something like :

```
class Foobar
{

   protected $_connection = null;

   public function __construct( DBConnect $db )  
   {
      $this->_connection = $db;
   }

   public function some_function()
   {
      $db = $this->_connection;
      // Do processing with $db, etc.
   }

}
```

And you use this class like this :

```
$db = new DBConnection(  /* your password , user , host , etc. */);

$stuff = new FooBar( $db );
$stuff->some_function();

$blah = new DifferentClass( $db );
```

This way you share the same connection with all the classes that require it. And now the class `FooBar` is not responsible for making connection or has to know your connection details.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Make the `$db` variable private, and use it via a getter.

Solution 2: Implement a singleton pattern on the dbal side.

Answer (score 0):

Even when calling a static method from an instance (not recommended), you do not have 
access to `$this`, so your class will fatal.

```
class sns {
   public static function moo() {
      var_dump($this->fng);
   }
   public function goo() {
      var_dump($this);
   }
}

sns::moo();
$_ = new sns;
$_->moo();
$_->goo();
```

As another poster has indicated from the php manual.

`$db` however can be defined statically instead so it only needs to be created once regardless of whether the object is an instance or not.